# publish the news of my direct website on my Twitter

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I made this code to publish the news of my direct website on my Twitter, but is not working and can not identify the error, since it does not return anything. Does not work and no error, just nothing happens. I searched many places but could not find a solution. Can someone help me?

```
$resultado = 'Publicar no Twitter';

 require_once 'twitteroauth.php';

 define("CONSUMER_KEY","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
 define("CONSUMER_SECRET","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
 define("OAUTH_TOKEN","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
 define("OAUTH_SECRET","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

 $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN,   OAUTH_SECRET);
 $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
 $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $resultado));
```

Answer (score 1):

To see the error replace the last line with:

```
$response =  $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' =>
$resultado));
```

and add another line

```
var_dump($response);
```

then go back and tell here what it says